# Can't understand a reduction formula question

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't even understand the question. Pls help me T_T

[image]

Hope any one can help me answer this question. Homework too hard T_T
Appreciate .... ^_^

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Have you tried integrating by parts?

Comment: What means T_T ?

Comment: Do you know what a reduction formula is?

Comment: Also, for goodness' sake don't close this. The OP has specifically stated that they don't even understand the question. There's a point where demanding the asker "show effort" is equivalent to not letting people use the site if they're not very good at math.

Comment: To me T_T looks like a crying person.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: Yup. T_T means a crying face. Ermm.... I have search for reduction formula from internet already... But I still can't got the meaning of it. But anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The answer itself is guiding you.

Rewrite $$\tan(x)^n=\tan(x)^{n-2} \Big(1+\tan(x)^{2} \Big)-\tan(x)^{n-2}$$ and notice that $ \Big(1+\tan(x)^{2} \Big)$ is just the derivative of $\tan(x)$. So now, if you integrate, you have $$I_n=\int \tan(x)^n~dx=\int \tan(x)^{n-2}~d(\tan(x))-\int \tan(x)^{n-2}~dx$$ The last integral is $I_{n-2}$ and the middle one is just $$\frac{\tan ^{n-1}(x)}{n-1}$$ As a result $$I_n=\frac{\tan ^{n-1}(x)}{n-1}-I_{n-2}$$

I am sure that you can take from here and finish.

Comment: Thank you Claude Leibovici. ^_^

Comment: @Reaper Remember that you also need to evaluate the term $uv$ between the lower and upper bounds of the integral as it is definite! $$ \int_{a}^{b} u \dfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x} \text{ d}x = uv \Bigg|_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b} v \dfrac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x} \text{ d}x$$

Comment: Thank you shisui ... No wonder I got stuck on the middle part ;)

Comment: @Reaper. You are very welcome !